# Reach licensedContent value on Youtube Api - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, youtube

In an effort to get consistent music search returns on Youtube API, I resorted to separate licensed content to non-licensed one.

The Json from the call is this:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/Y0E2MZ3qwZc8Z7rZDINIYA1uY0I\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/Xup77LEmvulitH-oe1DkTBPumV4\"",
   "id": "plIZho8Nd2g",
   "contentDetails": {
    "duration": "PT4M34S",
    "dimension": "2d",
    "definition": "hd",
    "caption": "true",
    "licensedContent": false,
    "projection": "rectangular"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

But I can't seem to reach the value in the PHP foreach loop. Is anything wrong with my code?

```
<?php

$api = "MY API KEY";

$link2 = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&id=plIZho8Nd2g&key=" . $api;

$video2 = file_get_contents($link2);

$video2 = json_decode($video2, true);


foreach ($video['items'] as $data) {
    foreach ($data['contentDetails'] as $data2) {
        $licensed = $data2['licensedContent'];

        echo $licensed . "<br>";


    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be getting some warnings which would help you solve this. There are a few little issues:

1. Typo: `foreach ($video['items'] as $data) {` - `$video` should be `$video2`
2. `contentDetails` is an object, not an array. So by doing a foreach loop on it you're looping through each property name individually. Therefore none of the properties will *contain* `licensedContent`. One of them will *be* `licensedContent`, but since we know we want that one, we can just access it directly.
3. Since `licensedContent` (and by extension `$licensed`) is a boolean, and is set to `false`, `echo` will not actually output anything visible - this is a quirk of the echo command in PHP. We can fix it by checking the value and then echoing an appropriate string.

Put all that together and this is what you get:

```
foreach ($video2['items'] as $data) {
    $licensed = $data['contentDetails']['licensedContent'];
    echo ($licensed == false ? "false" : "true")."<br/>";
}
```

Live demo here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7ca09960ec3e86ccb4bd49038ad851c3c93ef5de