# Get the first result of a PHP foreach loop json for YOUTUBE API

Tags: php, json, api, youtube, iteration

For some reason after getting the valid results of the iteration, the break; method does not stop the rest of results from appearing.

I need the first false licensedContent as a result...

```
<?php
$link2 = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&id=".$vid."&key=". $api;

$video2 = file_get_contents($link2);
$video2 = json_decode($video2, true);

foreach ($video2['items'] as $data) {

    $licensed = $data['contentDetails']['licensedContent'];
    $id = $data['id'];

    if ($licensed == false) {
      echo 'https://m.youtube.com/watch?v='.$vid; 
      echo ($licensed == false ? "false" : "true")."<br/>";
      break;
    }
}
?>
```

But I can't seem to solve what I'm doing wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hey, I answered your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53098491/reach-licensedcontent-value-on-youtube-api-php) earlier today. If it helped (you're using my code, so I assume it did), please remember to mark it as "accepted" (click the tick next to the answer so it turns green). Then people will know it was useful in future. Thanks. If it didn't help somehow, please leave a comment so it can be improved or further help given. This site works on feedback - if you don't accept answers or vote for them, people won't help in future.

Comment: Unless it is a typo, you are missing the closing curly bracket `}` to end your foreach loop

Comment: It's a typo, I copied only that part of the code. I get results correctly, each video id separately, but still can't get only the first one. And ADyson, I am earning points to vote and comment, let me try again if I can upvote since your answer is working, many thanks.

Comment: Anyway, your code should be fine, except, it will output the same thing no matter which item it stops on. That's because `$vid` is not changed by your loop, and everything else you output is hard-coded. Did you perhaps mean to use `$id` instead of `$vid` to append to the youtube URL?

Comment: Yep, it is id. But it was the typo mtr.web mentioned, that was the problem.

Comment: Here's [a demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9c1dc33caef02126f2f94cf5502023da83159bc1) showing what I mean. Notice it stops on the 2nd item (because that's the first one with licensed  = false) and outputs its ID, instead of the $vid.

Comment: The typo mtr mentioned would mean your code did not work at all, you'd have a syntax error showing. Nothing to do with the problem you stated in the question. That's far more likely to be to do with use of $id vs $vid.

Comment: Correct, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be fine, except, it will output the same thing no matter which item it stops on. So you won't be able to tell which item it found.

That's because `$vid` is not changed by your loop, and everything else you output is hard-coded.

I think perhaps you want to use `$id` instead of `$vid` in the output, to get the ID of the specific item found by the code:

```
echo 'https://m.youtube.com/watch?v='.$id;
```

Here's a live demo showing the result of doing that: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9c1dc33caef02126f2f94cf5502023da83159bc1